# Oracle equivalent query for this postgress query - CONFLICT

Tags: oracle

Following is a query from postgress.

```
CREATE TABLE testing2 (
    testing2_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    description varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO testing2(testing2_id,description) values (1,'NEW') 
ON CONFLICT (testing2_id) DO UPDATE SET description = 'UPDATE';
```

Does oracle provide an equivalent for conflict (upsert)?

Comment: Do you just mean [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html)? That's Oracle's 'upsert' command.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Is this concept same as merge?

Comment: If I execute second time, still it will be only one row in PG.

Comment: Yes - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=485db536ea4698a18a41f4372568966e).